# How to check if "8-puzzle" with n tiles is solvable

Tags: algorithms, puzzle

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/293527/412518) which got some good answers on how to check if an 8-puzzle is solvable. But what if there are less than 8 tiles on the grid? How to check if a puzzle with n tiles is solvable?

For n=7 tiles, this would be the goal state:

```
1|2|3
-+-+-
4|5|6
-+-+-
7| |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that with one open slot half the puzzles are unsolvable, basically because two neighboring tiles have been switched ('inverted'). (or: as some put it: there have been an odd number of such inversions, and as you make moves, there will always remain an odd number of inversions).

But with two open slots, you can always get any two tiles $A$ and $B$ next to each other, and next to the open 2 spots, making a square:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
& \\
\hline
\end{array}

And with those two open slots we can of course easily switch the position of those two tiles:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
B & A \\
\hline
& \\
\hline
\end{array}

So, you can do *any* number of inversions with two open slots. Hence, with 2 open spots, it is always solvable (for *any* size board $m \times n$ with $m,n \ge 2$).

Comment: By one missing tile, you mean 8 tiles in total, not 7? What do you mean by saying two neighboring tiles have been switched? For sure the board can be more mixed than what that sounds.

Comment: @Antti_M  Yes, an unsolvable board can be mixed up more than that, but you can always get an unsolvable board to a state where only the 7 and the 8 are switched (or any two neighboring squares).

Comment: @Antti_M  And you can always take the line of reasoning that for an unsolvable 8-puzzle, there will always be an odd number of inversions ... with the 7-puzzle, you can get *any* number of inversions.

Comment: @Antti_M Oh, and yes, by '1 missing tile' I meant the 8-puzzle. I guess I should have said '1 open slot'